# Android default settings restore without losing data

Tags: settings

I was wondering if it's possible to restore an android default settings without deleting any data or apps? It's because I buy android tablets then I install my app on it then I sell it back to a customer but I want it to go back when it came out of the box to ask for settings again once the customer turns on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restoring factory defaults without deleting *any apps or data* is a contradiction in terms, as that's exactly what the reset does (see: [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset)).

Could it be you just want *your app* to survive, but don't care about everything else being reset? That could be done by making the app a *system app* (see: [system-apps](/questions/tagged/system-apps)), which requires the device to be *rooted* (see: [rooting](/questions/tagged/rooting), [root](/questions/tagged/root)) in the first place.

Apart from that, the answer is "No". As soon as your customer applies a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset), your app will be removed as well.